# Why does calling a variable only read first line of the file

Tags: python

I have the following code to read files on the folder, which seems to be working fine with `print(line)`, but it brings only one line while calling it through a variable (`line`). What am I doing wrong here?

```
import fileinput
import glob

folderpath =  r"\path\*"

file_list = glob.glob(folderpath + "/*.txt")

with fileinput.FileInput(files=(file_list), mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        #line = line.decode() 
        line = line.rstrip()
        print(line)
```

Comment: Because after the loop is done, `line` contains the last value you assigned to it.

Comment: What does this have to do with the pandas or numpy tags?